# Extracting HSD.test() result

Tags: r

```
plant.lm <- lm(Buy ~ product, data = dataset)
plant.av <- aov(plant.lm)
tukeytest<-HSD.test(plant.av, trt = 'product')
tukeytest

> tukeytest
$statistics
  MSerror  Df     Mean       CV       MSD
  1.12648 202 3.686275 28.79215 0.2930452

$parameters
   test           name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey product.or.block   2         2.788514  0.05

$means
        Buy       std   r Min Max Q25 Q50 Q75
3 3.911765 0.9657803 102   1   5   3   4   5
4 3.460784 1.1490122 102   1   5   3   4   4

$comparison
NULL

$groups
   Q22.Buy groups
3 3.911765      a
4 3.460784      b
```

This is an example I saw online, my question is if we can have the 'product' under a column header with the $groups output for me to subset the comparison categories with the groups

```
For eg:
$groups
   trt Buy groups
    3 3.911765      a
    4 3.460784      b
```

Comment: Please include a small reproducible example when asking for help. It will help us help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```r
library(agricolae)

# Fit data
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
tukeytest <- HSD.test(fit, "Species")

# Extract data and rename column names
out <- tukeytest$groups
new_out <- cbind(trt = rownames(out), out)

# Remove row names
rownames(new_out) <- NULL

# New data
new_out
#>          trt Sepal.Length groups
#> 1  virginica        6.588      a
#> 2 versicolor        5.936      b
#> 3     setosa        5.006      c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>